# Making a button look pressed in

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse to write the android application. I've added some standard buttons from the Form Widgets tab and successfully got them opening new windows which display additional buttons.

I would like the button that was pressed, to change appearance and continue to look pressed in after it is selected.

Comment: Do you need [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create xml file using the button image like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
   <item 
      android:drawable="@drawable/closebutton" />
 </selector>
```

add the color folder in values

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>    
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>  
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

can use selector

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_focused="true" 
              android:state_pressed="false" 
              android:drawable="@drawable/button_settings" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" 
              android:state_pressed="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/button_settings" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" 
              android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_settings_selected" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_settings" />
    </selector>
```

now set this drawable on background property of button in XML, now in coding take a boolean flag when button is pressed set the flag and set the bacground of the button(selected image) and on again click reset flag value and change the imageBackground to the selector again, thats it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton and change the background of the button.
you can use this kind of images depends of you need. Like this https://web.archive.org/web/20160429124711/http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was after. I'll have a paly with all three to get a better understanding of the differences. Thank you all very much for your quick and helpful answers.