# Selector.xml is not working when clicked on the image button

Tags: android, css-selectors, imagebutton

I use the following selector to change image of image button, when I click on it. But this does not work most of the times. Only for few buttons it works. Don't know what the cause here is

```
 mapselector.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Button Pressed -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/mapiconover"/>
</selector>
```

And in the button,

Am doing like this,

```
  <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap" android:layout_centerInParent="true"  android:src="@drawable/mapselector"
    android:background="@drawable/map" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ImageButton>
```

but still image is not changing when I click.

Any guess for this?

Comment: What's the name of the xml file that you have your selector in?

Comment: @Kurtis..name of the selector is mapselector.xml. I have set that in the image button below.

Comment: you have create like this, follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567521/making-a-button-look-pressed-in/7568010#7568010

Comment: @Polam, I feel that is same as I did except that it has a color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have create like this in the ImageButton xml

create xml file using the button image like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/backbutton" />
  <item 
   android:drawable="@drawable/closebutton" />
</selector>
```

add that xml file as background for IMageButton

```
<ImageButton                 
    android:layout_height="50px" 
    android:layout_width="50px" 
    android:id="@+id/settings" 
    android:background="@drawable/settings_button" //setting_button in
                                                         the xml file            
    android:text="Settings"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but you could try changing your selector to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Button Pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/mapiconover"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/map" />

</selector>
```

And your image button to this:

```
  <ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"  
     android:background="@drawable/mapselector"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: it is also not giving me the result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was because of

> android:state_xxxx

conflict. It solved by clarifying the conditions between enabled and pressed. I used the following code to get different states between press and normal state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#1094ff"
                android:endColor="#7eb6e3"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="#505050" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#0075d4"
                android:endColor="#0070cb"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#b9b9b9"
                android:endColor="#848484"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="#505050" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This example uses different gradient and stroke for different states. You can also use your drawable instead. Just create a file like "mybutton.xml" in your drawable folder. then set the background property of your button like this:

> android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

I hope it be helpful.